# Facebook php connect

Tags: php, facebook

Im trying to connect to facebook using php-sdk. facebook login window appears when i click login, i fill my username and password and then it redirects to same page, saying not connected. I am new with facebook php. Help me

```
<?php
  require_once("php-sdk/src/facebook.php");

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '---',
  'secret' => '---',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
//
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}


?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>php-sdk</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
      }
      h1 a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #3b5998;
      }
      h1 a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>php-sdk</h1>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
    <?php else: ?>
      <div>
        Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
        <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
      </div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <h3>PHP Session</h3>
    <pre><?php print_r($_SESSION); ?></pre>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <h3>You</h3>
      <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">

      <h3>Your User Object (/me)</h3>
      <pre><?php print_r($user_profile); ?></pre>
    <?php else: ?>
      <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
    <?php endif ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to check your call back url in your facebook app settings.

Answer (score 1):

Please place your `appId` and `secret` and follow the code below. You should also use the latest [Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk)

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '111111111',// your appId here
  'secret' => '1a1a1a1a1a1a1',// your app secret here
));


$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();



} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide certain information to the app you just created. The call back url is needed. Please check the information at the facebook end.